# given an array of size n. How do i find the sum of all the combination of k values in the array

Tags: arrays, sum

given an array of size n. I have to find all the possible combination of k value in the array where k<=n.

Comment: By writing some code.  In some programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty easy in Python as the code reads almost like the question: Return a sum of all combinations of length *k* from the given array, or list in case of Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
from itertools import combinations


def calculate_sums(items, k):
    return (sum(combination) for combination in combinations(items, k))


def main():
    for value in calculate_sums([23, 42, 4711], 2):
        print(value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints 65, 4734, and 4753 which is 23+42, 23+4711, and 42+4711.

Comment: thank you, but is there any similar functions in other programming languages... like java or c++...???

Comment: @NavaneetthaSundararaj There are libraries for many languages. A quick search for _java combinatorics_ lead me to [de.bezier.math.combinatorics](http://bezier.de/processing/libs/combi/documentation/de/bezier/math/combinatorics/package-summary.html) and [combinatoricslib](https://github.com/dpaukov/combinatoricslib).